# overriding a check event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a DataGridView with checkboxes. The checkboxes were automagically thrown in because my data source has a boolean "Selected" property (if that matters).

Googling the [forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5acb4c02-a791-419f-9bd5-bea360a1cfdf/how-to-make-checkboxes-in-datagridview-mutually-exclusive) here I have been able to implement a mutual exclusion mechanism of sorts that works okay.

```
//  unselect all the other ones
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvr.Cells[e.ColumnIndex]).Value = false;
}
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = true;
```

The problem is if a user clicks a checked box the box unchecks. The use case here is that something has to always be selected.

My first approach was to make sure an existing column index was having its value set to true. And it was. But the problem continues ...

My second approach was to set DataGridViewCellEventArgs's handled event to true to stop anything down stream from interfering with our specific use case condition. Apparently this class doesn't have a handled property (neither do its base classes).

My third approach was to call Application.DoEvents() ten thousand times and then set Value to true to see if whatever was unchecking the box would get processed in there and then I could undo it. But apparently this process doesn't happen until after the event handler method completes.

How should I do this?

Comment: your question is not clear to me. I don't get what you want with your datagridview, you want to do something like the code you posted does but you don't want to use `foreach` or any `loop`?

Comment: @KingKing: Well, I think I need that. The problem is that some how there seems to be some other process that un-checks what I have checked there.

Answer (score 1):

> The use case here is that something has to always be selected.

You need to handle the `CellContentClick` of datagridview. Then you can check if there is any checkbox that is still checked. After doing that you can call `CancelEdit` or `CommitEdit` based on your use case.

Comment: This gets me some of the way (so +1). Unfortunately a double-click event seems to be able to undo this. I tried creating a dummy double-click method and directing both events to the same method, but neither work.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
// A list of the check box cell so we can use LINQ to access them
private List<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell> checkBoxCellList = new List<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>();

private DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

private void dataGridViewBuild() {
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cbcolumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false);
    cbcolumn.Name = "Selected";
    cbcolumn.HeaderText = cbcolumn.Name;            
    this.dgv.Columns.Add(cbcolumn);

    // Add 100 rows
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        dgv.Rows.Add();
    }

    // Get all of the checkbox cells and add them to the list
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgv.Rows) {                
        this.checkBoxCellList.Add((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["Selected"]);
    }            

    // Subscribe to the value changed event for the datagridview
    this.dgv.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellValueChanged);            

    this.Controls.Add(this.dgv);
}

void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {

    // Get the cell checkbox cell for the row that was changed
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)this.dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

    // If the value is true then set all other checkboxcell values to false with LINQ
    if (checkBoxCell.Value != null && Convert.ToBoolean(checkBoxCell.Value)) {
        this.checkBoxCellList.FindAll(cb => Convert.ToBoolean(cb.Value) == true && cb != checkBoxCell).ForEach(cb => cb.Value = false);
    }

    // If the checkboxcell was made false and no other is true then reset the value to true       
    if (this.checkBoxCellList.FindAll(cb => Convert.ToBoolean(cb.Value) == true).Count == 0) {
            checkBoxCell.Value = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `CellValueChanged` is not even fired when checking and unchecking the checkbox cell? I've tested with this event, it's a little strange, maybe for checkboxcell only.

Comment: It fires when the data is being saved to the datagridview. Click the checkbox and then click to another row and it should fire.

Comment: @jiverson: I had the same experience as KingKing. I don't see that event get fired reliably. +1 for introducing me to the foreach lambda method. Last I checked it wasn't in the 101 linq tutorials.

Comment: @jiverson: my test harness appears to be 4.0 but in production it will probably have to be 3.5.

Comment: @jiverson: I've confirmed your code behaves as expected (the value gets set to true or false correctly), but something comes along and un-does it for some reason.

Comment: The code will set the check back if the one that is checked gets unchecked by the user and no other checkboxcell is checked. Is that what is happening?

Comment: @jiverson: That's how it should work, but it does not. It lets me check as many boxes as I want and when I move the focus off it un-does any unchecking I do. I've confirmed the checkbox list contains the correct number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues (Ben Zoski) recommended removing the checkboxes altogether and just using the data grid view's natural click selection to uniquely identify a row:

[image]

To do this I set the SelectionMode property of the data grid view to: "FullRowSelect".

I'm a little apprehensive that users won't be familiar with the convention of highlighting certain rows in a grid to select something (in the same way that they are familiar with checking a box), but the single checkbox approach is complicated and unreliable (although I suspect it is a better approach if you want users to be able to select multiple rows).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you answered your own question by changing directions, but I thought I'd throw a potential solution your way in case you wanted to stick with the CheckBoxes. Consider this code:

```
private static int _previousClickedCheckBoxRowIndex;

private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    if ((dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty) & (dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == dgv.Columns["CheckBoxColumn"]))
    {
        dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == dgv.Columns["CheckBoxColumn"])
    {
        dgv.CellValueChanged -= dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;

        if (_previousClickedCheckBoxRowIndex == e.RowIndex)
        {
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value =
                !((bool)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);

            dgv.RefreshEdit();

        }
        else
        {
            dgv.Rows[_previousClickedCheckBoxRowIndex].Cells["CheckBoxColumn"].Value = false;
            _previousClickedCheckBoxRowIndex = e.RowIndex;                               
        }

        dgv.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
    }
}
```

Basically what the code is doing is, by keeping track of the last CheckBox row index the user clicked in your `DataGridView`, it'll either deny the user from un-checking the only current checked box, or switch the box to exclusively checked if it was previously unselected.

The reason for handling `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` is that, by default, the `DataGridView` leaves the `CheckBoxCell` in edit mode when checked. This commits it as a change to the grid instead. The reason for unsubscribing then resubscribing the `CellValueChanged` event is to prevent an infinite loop when programmatically changing values inside the function itself.

Make sure you change the indexing string "CheckBoxColumn" to the column in your grid.

Not the most elegant code, but it's fairly short and sweet. Hope it works for you if you decide to go that route.